# View requires multiple API endpoints -- how can I speed up requests in non-blocking fashion?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to render a view that depends on multiple API endpoints. What is the best practice -- the waterfall of callbacks seems slow. My only thought is I could have each request reference a callback that waits until all three are complete before rendering -- that way, I can initialize all GET in a non-blocking fashion.

API is just a module that makes calls to the API with 'GET' requests and returns result.

Thank you in advance!

```
app.get('/:name/:id', function(req,res){
    var name = req.param('name'),
        id = req.param('id');
    api.getName(name, id, function(err,Name){

      if (err)
        return res.render('404', { error : "Non-existent"});

      api.getNameComments(name, id, function(err, comments){
        api.getNameLikes(name,id,function(err,likes){
          res.render('project', {
            project: project.response,
            comments: comments.response,
            likes: likes.response
          });
        });
      });
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: Bluebird's [`Promise.join()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisejoinpromisethenablevalue-promises-function-handler---promise) would be great for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the calls don't depend on each other, you can run them all in parallel using the async library, https://github.com/caolan/async .